# Setting up AWS Glue to crawl Qubole

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, aws-glue, qubole

Currently I work with Qubole to access Hive data. I've added metadata from several databases, and want to add all the Hive metadata to AWS Glue. Is this possible? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add all the metadata from [Qubole](https://www.qubole.com/blog/qubole-now-supports-glue-data-catalog/) to AWS Glue catalog, but Glue crawler doesn't support Qubole as source.

You can use AWS Glue Sync Agent to synchronize metadata changes from Hive metastore in Qubole to AWS Glue Data Catalog.Refer to [this](https://docs.qubole.com/en/latest/admin-guide/aws-glue/aws-glue-catalog.html) which talks about more on how to achieve.